# Counting only the MaxDate record in Oracle (Toad)

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, maxdate

With appropriate apologies to everyone as this is my first post, I'm just back into SQL queries after having been away for two and half years. And even then I wasn't the best. I want a Distinct Count of Persons (SSN) by Service (SHORT_NAM) but I only want to count their last record (with the `Max(EndDate)` irrespective of the the `Short_Nam`).

The problem is that a person can change services in the middle of year. The following code gives me everyone with their `Service` and `EndDate`. I can't figure out how to get a Distinct Count of the `SSN's` when using `Max(EndDate)` and grouping by `Short_Nam`. I only want to count the most recent record for them.

```
SELECT PLN.ENDDATE,
   PLN.SSN,
   SERV.SHORT_NAM    

FROM DDIS.CST_CST_PLN PLN
    INNER JOIN DDIS.CST_SERV SERV ON (SERV.PKSERVICE = PLN.FKSERVICE)
 WHERE TRIM(SERV.FISCALYR) = '2020' 
    AND STATUS IS NULL
    AND AUTHORIZED = 1
    AND TRIM(SERV.GROUPCODE) IN ('RES','SEM')
    AND NOT (SERV.SERVICE LIKE '%OUT%' OR
        SERV.SERVICE LIKE'%NEEDS%' OR
        SERV.SERVICE LIKE'%SNA%')
```

I've tried various things but seem to be running in circles. So If I have the following records:

```
SSN         EndDate   Short_Nam
111-11-1111  01/19/2020 FAM3
111-11-1111  06/30/2020 FAM3
222-22-2222  12/31/2019 FAM3
222-22-2222  04/20/2020 FAM3
222-22-2222  06/30/2020 SIL
333-33-3333  06/30/2020 FAM3
```

I want the results being:

```
USERS  Service
  2     FAM3
  1     SIL
```

Right now with everything I've tried using MaxDates and such, SSN 222-22-2222 will get counted under both FAM3 and SIL.

Where am I going wrong? I've tried setting up a temporary table in an initial WHERE clause. I've tried an Analytic Function something like 'max(my_date) over (partition by userid) max_my_date' but that also failed.

Any help? Thanks for the guidance. I'll get back up to speed slowly.

Hint to all of you. Don't take 2 1/2 years off! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your results seem consistent with:

```
select service, count(distinct ssn)
from t
group by service;
```

I am not sure that you actually care about the "last" user.  You seem to just want to count each distinct user.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the input but I don't think you grasped what I was asking for. Yes, I can get what you are talking about. But I don't want that. I only want to count the user in the **last** service the user was in. For example, in the list above I only want to count 222-22-2222 in SIL and not count them in FAM3. Hope that helps.